How to waive off shipping charges in Woocommerce checkout without using a coupon?
I had built an express checkout for one of my woocommerce store and I'm builting a functionality of 0 shipping charges for all prepaid orders. I have one checkbox to enable/disable COD in the checkout page and based on the selection of that checkbox I'm trying to toggle the shipping charges. I also want to reflect the changes on the checkout page frontend itself like it should show the shipping charges and refreshes the order total in the order summary only if COD is enabled else It should show 0 shipping charges & order total remains unchanged.
After some research I found one hook woocommerce_package_rates that basically helps to tweak the shipping charges and I tried this:
add_action('woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_woocommerce_zero_shipping_for_prepaid_orders', 10, 2);
function custom_woocommerce_zero_shipping_for_prepaid_orders($rates, $package) {
    // Check for the chosen payment method
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    // If the chosen payment method is NOT 'cod' (Cash on Delivery), set shipping to zero
    if ($chosen_payment_method !== 'cod') {
        foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
            // Set the cost of each shipping method to zero
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;

            // If you want to also set taxes to zero, uncomment the line below
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = array_map(function($tax) { return 0; }, $rates[$rate_key]->taxes);
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}

But this hook triggers on page load. It might work for the calculations behind the scene post placing an order. But, I'm not able to hook this with custom ajax calls to recalculate the prices on the checkout page itself.
Is there any other way which can help to meet the expectations?
P.S: I already tried to make it work with coupons. I don't want to implement this functionality by using coupons.

I'm not using default pages of woocommerce. Created custom flow

"default pages" doesn't mean anything, are you using Classic checkout page (shortcode) or checkout Blocks page?

I'm using the default classic checkout page. But In my checkout journey user doesn't lands to checkout page for placing an order i.e. its a checkout popup on PDP, I have created custom flow by using hooks and default woocommerce methods.
You can check here: https://www.ubnaturals.com

There are multiple ways to handle that:
Note: The following will only work on classic (legacy shortcode) checkout page, but not on newly checkout Blocks. Checkout Blocks does not allow this kind of customization.
1). Using your current code (reset shipping methods cost, based on payment method)
There are some required missing things with your current code, to make it work.
Try the following code replacement:
// Utility function: Reset shipping taxes
function zero_taxes( $tax ) {
    return 0;
}

// Set zero shipping cost for prepaid orders
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'disable_shipping_cost_for_prepaid_orders', 10, 2);
function disable_shipping_cost_for_prepaid_orders($rates, $package) {
    // Target other payment methods than "COD"
    if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') !== 'cod' ) {
        foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
            if( $rate->cost > 0 ) {
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost  = 0;  // Null shipping costs
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = array_map('zero_taxes', $rate->taxes);  // Null shipping taxes costs 
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

// Update checkout on payment method change (jQuery)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'trigger_update_checkout_on_payment_method_change' );
function trigger_update_checkout_on_payment_method_change(){
    wc_enqueue_js("$('form.checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name=payment_method]', function(){
        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
    });");
}

// Refresh shipping methods on payment method change (Mandatory)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods_on_payment_method_change' );
function refresh_shipping_methods_on_payment_method_change() {
    if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') ) {
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ) {
             WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, false );
        }
    }
}

Code goes in function.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
2). Using an additional Free shipping method (without restrictions):
In WooCommerce shipping settings, you will add to each related shipping zone, a free shipping method without restrictions, like:

Here, we will enable only free shipping for prepaid orders.
Then use the following code instead (where you will define in the first function the related free shipping rate ID(s)):
// Free shipping only for prepaid orders
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'free_shipping_for_prepaid_orders', 10, 2);
function free_shipping_for_prepaid_orders($rates, $package) {
    // Define below the additional free shipping method rate IDs
    $free_rates = array('free_shipping:3', 'free_shipping:9');

    // Target other payment methods than "COD", enable free shipping only
    if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') !== 'cod' ) {
        foreach ( $free_rates as $free_rate ) {
            if ( isset($rates[$free_rate]) ) {
                return array( $free_rate => $rates[$free_rate]);
            }
        }
    } 
    // For COD payments, remove free shipping
    else {
        foreach ( $free_rates as $free_rate ) {
            if ( isset($rates[$free_rate]) ) {
                unset($rates[$free_rate]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

// Update checkout on payment method change (jQuery)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'trigger_update_checkout_on_payment_method_change' );
function trigger_update_checkout_on_payment_method_change(){
    wc_enqueue_js("$('form.checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name=payment_method]', function(){
        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
    });");
}

// Refresh shipping methods on payment method change (Mandatory)
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods_on_payment_method_change' );
function refresh_shipping_methods_on_payment_method_change() {
    if ( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') ) {
        foreach (WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ) {
             WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, false );
        }
    }
}

Code goes in function.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Thanks for the solution. I want to ask one thing here can I hook this shipping calculations exactly when the cart totals calculations happens?

I'm just trying to adjust the solution with my custom flow before I accept or upvote. Anyways, This solution helped me to understand how can we tweak shipping methods. Can I ask exactly when the hook woocommerce_package_rates triggers?

I think it's triggered on classic cart and checkout pages with wc_cart_totals_shipping_html() function.… On cart and checkout blocks I suppose that there is something similar.
